# Express Session Not Saving

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I know other people have run into this, but my Express session is not saving. I looked through as many questions and threads and I could but couldn't find a fix. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Here's where it's initialized:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'BigSecret',
  resave: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 7, //seven days
    secure: false
  },
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

And where it's used in the route:

```
router.get('/route', async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.session.views) {
        req.session.views = 0;
    } else {
        req.session.views++
    }
    console.log(req.session);

    ...the rest of the route...

    res.render('pages', {
        key: val,
        anotherKey: anotherVal
    }
});
```

Also, for some context, I'm returning a rendered EJS page so that's what the render is at the end.

Comment: What is "Saving"? To a database? Or where?

Comment: Since you are using `resave` I could imagine that the issue is in a different route. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#user-content-resave) Does it work with `resave: false`?

Comment: @VasylBoroviak express-sessions uses memorysave unless otherwise specified

Comment: @ChristianFritz that was my initial thought so I've only been testing with the single route

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue may be in this code here:

```js
if (!req.session.views) {
  req.session.views = 0;
} else {
  req.session.views++;
}
```

The first request, the value of `req.session.views` will be `undefined`, so `!req.session.views` will evaluate to `true` and you’ll set the value to `0`.

The next request, and every request thereafter, the value of `req.session.views` will be `0`. Each time `!0` will evaluate to `true` and you’ll just set the value to `0` again.

You probably want to change it to something like `if (!('views' in req.session))` or `if (typeof req.session.views === 'undefined')` etc.

Alternatively you may wish to just set `req.session.views = 1;` on the first request since this is the first view. Then on the second request `!req.session.views` will be `!1` which will evaluate to `false`, and your value will be incremented.

Comment: Great catch. I quite like `req.session.views ??= 1` as a simple one-liner option

Comment: ^^ For real great catch! Thanks! (lol I'm sorry too)